# Word macro for Header and Footer from template

Tags: vba, ms-word, header, footer

Colleagues,

I need to create a macro in Word where I can replace a header and footer for a current document based on a template saved in another standard document.

My code:

```
  Dim docTemplate As Document
  Dim strTemplate As String
  Dim hdr1 As HeaderFooter
  Dim hdr2 As HeaderFooter
  Dim doc As Document

  Set doc = ActiveDocument
  strTemplate = "D:\OneDrive\Profissional\template.doc"
  Set docTemplate = Documents.Open(strTemplate)
  Set hdr1 = docTemplate.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)
  Set hdr2 = doc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
  hdr1.Range.Copy
  hdr2.Range.Paste
  docTemplate.Close False
```

However, it is only copying the header, it does not copy the formatting with the tables, not the footer, which is also mounted on tables.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: See, for example, post #2 in: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/20788-replace-apply-new-header-multiple-files.html

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but it didn't work out here. When I run the macro, I can clean the footer and the current header, I can also change the background color of the paper, but I can't copy the header and footer of the standard template document, even though it opens and closes, it apparently can't copy in memory and not even paste into the current document.